# Build EF core Where() predicate at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I have written a piece of code which builds an EF Core `Where()` predicate at runtime. I have never done this before, but for the requirement I had to do it.

The requirement is simply to get data from the db within 7 days of `CreatedOn` or `UpdatedOn`.

The previous version before the refactor was to call the database 7 time in a loop which had performance problems.

The current implementation works as expected and returns the expected results.

This is the current code:

```
private async Task SevenDaysCashOutFloor(DateTimeOffset today, IQueryable<BillPaymentVoucher> pastBillPayments, IQueryable<JournalVoucherPaymentVoucher> pastJournalVoucherPayments, CancellationToken token)
{
        Expression<Func<BillPaymentVoucher, bool>> predicate = null!;
        Expression<Func<BillPaymentVoucher, bool>> aggregatedPredicate = null!;
        BinaryExpression binaryExpression = null!;

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BillPaymentVoucher));

        today = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        for (int days = 0; days < 7; days++)
        {
            var date = today.AddDays(-days);

            predicate = (entity) => (
                                        (entity.UpdatedOn.HasValue && entity.UpdatedOn.Value.Date == date.Date) ||
                                        (entity.UpdatedOn.HasValue == false && entity.CreatedOn.Date == date.Date)
                                    );

            binaryExpression = Expression.OrElse(ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(aggregatedPredicate ?? predicate, param),
                                                 ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(predicate, param));

            aggregatedPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<BillPaymentVoucher, bool>>(binaryExpression, param);
        }

        var finalPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<BillPaymentVoucher, bool>>(binaryExpression, param);

        pastBillPayments = pastBillPayments.Where(finalPredicate);          
}
```

I am building the predicate at runtime which is needed by the `Where()` in a `for` loop.

It all works as expected, but I want to know:

1. if this is the proper way of writing it?
2. should I be using the `Expression Tree` which is complex?
3. is there a simple way to achieve this?
4. can this code be refactored?

I have never worked with expression trees before.

Comment: If your code works, it probably doesn't belong on SO. You should try posting it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You do know you're not limited to just `==` and `!=` in predicates, don't you? You shouldn't need to do 7 separate comparisons to determine if something occurred within the last 7 days, just use `>=`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ,with time the 7 may vary, it already varied a few times

Comment: But still, the whole thing should still just be something like `var notBefore = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-7).Date; pastBillPayments = pastBillPayments.Where(e=>e.UpdateOn.HasValue && e.UpdateOn.Value >= notBefore || e.CreatedOn >= notBefore);`, unless your data includes future dates in which case it's a little more complex but not what you're constructing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, ho dumb i have been. what a waste of time. i just realized what u said in the above comment. it works the same after i changed the code as u said. thanks a lot man!!

Comment: `Where` is always constructed at runtime. There's no reason to use `entity.UpdatedOn.HasValue && entity.UpdatedOn.Value.Date`, it's enough to use `entity.UpdatedOn?.Date == date.Date`. This will be translated to SQL and eg `cast(UpdatedOn as date) ==@d1`. The actual condition should be `entity.UpdatedOn?.Date == date.Date || entity.CreatedOn?.Date == date.Date`. The entire expression loop could be replaced with a single expression comparing against multiple values. Or even `listOfDates.Contains(entity.UpdatedOn) || listOfDates.Contains(entity.CreatedOn)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ,i tried `it's enough to use entity.UpdatedOn?.Date == date.Date`, but it gives me compilation error

Comment: In this particular case you can use `UpdatedOn >= dateFrom && UpdatedOn < nextDay` . There's no need for a dynamic expression at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Where` is always constructed at runtime. There's no need to explicitly check for nulls either. The expressions will be translated to SQL which has explicit support for NULL values.

This method searches for rows whose `UpdatedOn` or `CreatedOn` fall in a range of days. You can probably replace it by creating a list of those days and using `Contains` :

```
var daysInWeek=Enumerable.Range(0,7)
                         .Select(i=>DateTime.Today.AddDays(-i))
                         .ToList();

pastBillPayments = pastBillPayments.Where(p=>daysInWeek.Contains(p.UpdatedOn.Date) 
                          || daysInWeek.Contains(p.CreatedOn.Date) );
```

This will generate :

```
WHERE ... cast(UpdatedOn as date) IN (@d1,@d2,...,@d7) OR 
          cast(CreatedOn as date) IN (@d1,@d2,...,@d7)
```

That's not optimal though. While some databases (eg SQL Server) can convert `cast(UpdatedOn as date) = ...` into a range search that can use indexes, they can't use the index statistics.

An even better query would be to explicitly search in a date range :

```
var dateTo=DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
var dateFrom=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6);

pastBillPayments = pastBillPayments
    .Where(p=> 
        (p.UpdatedOn >= dateFrom && p.UpdateOn  < dateTo) ||
        (p.CreatedOn >= dateFrom && p.CreatedOn < dateTo));
```

This eliminates any casting, allowing the server to use both indexes and statistics

Comment: i think it has to be daysInWeek in the daysInWeek .Contains() instead of listOfDates.Contains isnt it?